# Android.Views.InflateException: Binary XML file line #1: Binary XML file line #1: Error inflating class <unknown> error occure for AppCompat

Tags: xamarin.android, xamarin.forms

I am getting  Binary XML file line #1: Binary XML file line #1: Error inflating class  error occure for AppCompat error while trying to add tabbar and toolbar in android.Can anybody help me to come out of it.refering this link [AppCompact](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/platform-features/android/appcompat/)
Here is my code. This is Style`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<resources>
  <style name="MyTheme" parent="MyTheme.Base">
  </style>
  <style name="MyTheme.Splash" parent ="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/Splash</item>
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
  </style>
  <style name="MyTheme.Base" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/primary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/primaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/accent</item>
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@color/window_background</item>
    <item name="windowActionModeOverlay">true</item>
  </style>
  <style name="AppCompatDialogStyle" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog">
    <item name="colorAccent">#FF4081</item>
  </style>
</resources>
```

`This is code in Tabbar.axml and toolbar.axml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/sliding_tabs"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
    app:tabIndicatorColor="@android:color/white"
    app:tabGravity="fill"
    app:tabMode="fixed" />

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
    app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"/>
```

`and main activity`

```
public class FormsActivity : global::Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.FormsAppCompatActivity//FormsApplicationActivity//
    { protected override void OnCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            FormsAppCompatActivity.ToolbarResource = Resource.Layout.Toolbar;
            FormsAppCompatActivity.TabLayoutResource = Resource.Layout.Tabbar;
            base.OnCreate (savedInstanceState);}
```

`

Comment: Not 100% it matters.. But are your files called `Tabbar.xml` and `toolbar.xml`? Not that they should be named `.axml`. Also, check it the build action is set to `AndroidResource`

Comment: Its .axml nly ...and its built action is also AndroidResource

Comment: Also make sure you have the `xamarin.android.support.v7.appCompat` NuGet package installed and set the target SDK to Android 6.0

Comment: yes sir ....target sdk is Android 6.0(API level 23 -Marshmallow) and xamarin.android.support.v7.appCompat NuGet pkg is installed with version 25.3.1 and Xamarin.forms with version 2.3.4.247

Answer (score 0):

Try to uninstall the `Xamarin.Forms`, do a full clean, delete `bin/obj` folder, restart VS, install back the `Xamarin.Forms`, rebuild whole solution.

Comment: Thank you york ....but it wont work .Issue is just resolved by removing all android.support NuGet package and reinstalling it of version 23.0.0.0...finally came out of it....thanks once again for your time :)

Comment: @nitu, so sad, I use the same version as your question but cant reproduced your problem, so I think it's something wrong with Visual Studio. Are you using VS 2017?

Comment: No its 2015...Initially i had android.support packages with 25.3.1 the updated one which i have downgrade to 23.0.0.0

Comment: I get the same error in VS 2017 when trying to use Xamarin.Forms. Themes. Solution was to just not use themes. Sadly that's not a joke.

Comment: @user875234, you could file a bug report for Xamarin Team in [here](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues/new)